# Count matches in Mongodb $or

Tags: python, mongodb

Trying to count the matches across all columns.

I currently use this code to copy across certain fields from a Scrapy item.

```
def getDbModel(self, item):
    deal = { "name":item['name'] }

    if 'imageURL' in item:
        deal["imageURL"] = item['imageURL']
    if 'highlights' in item:
        deal['highlights'] = replace_tags(item['highlights'], ' ')
    if 'fine_print' in item:
        deal['fine_print'] = replace_tags(item['fine_print'], ' ')
    if 'description' in item:
        deal['description'] = replace_tags(item['description'], ' ')
    if 'search_slug' in item:
        deal['search_slug'] = item['search_slug']
    if 'dealURL' in item:
        deal['dealurl'] = item['dealURL']
```

Wondering how I would turn this into an OR search in mongodb.

I was looking at something like the below:

```
def checkDB(self,item): 
    # Check if the record exists in the DB
    deal = self.getDbModel(item)

    return self.db.units.find_one({"$or":[deal]})
```

Firstly, Is this the best method to be doing?

Secondly, how would I find the count of the amount of columns matched i.e. trying to limit records that match at least two columns.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way of counting the number of colum matches on MongoDBs end, it just kinda matches and then returns.

You would probably be better doing this client side, I am unsure exactly how you intend to use this count figure but there is no easy way, whether through MR or aggregation framework of doing this.

You could, in the aggregation framework, change your schema a little to put these colums within a `properties` field and then `$sum` the matches within the subdocuemnt. This is a good approach since you can also sort on it to create a type of relevance search (if that is what your intending).

As to whether this is a good approach depends. When using an `$or` MongoDB will use an index for each condition, this is a special case within MongoDB indexing, however it does mean you should take this into consideration when making an `$or` and ensure you have indexes to cover each condition.

You have also got to consider that MongoDB will effectively eval each clause and then merge the results to remove duplicates, which can be heavy for bigger `$or`s or a large working set.

Of course the format of your $or is wrong, you need an array of arrays of your fields. At the minute you have a single array with another array which has all your attributes. When used like this the attributes will actually have an `$and` condition between them so it won't work.

You could probably change your code to:

```
def getDbModel(self, item):
    deal = []
    deal[] = { "name":item['name'] }

    if 'imageURL' in item:
        deal[] = {"imageURL": tem['imageURL']}
    if 'highlights' in item:
        // etc

// Some way down
return self.db.units.find_one({"$or":deal})
```

NB: I am not a Python programmer

Hope it helps,